# Organizing custom library in rails 5 /app folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have `Simulator` module that's essential to my app, so I'm storing it in the `/app` folder for autoloading.  My folder structure looks like:

Right now, I have the module in `/app/simulator/simulator.rb` defined with subclasses inline:

```
module Simulator
  def self.run(params)
    #...
  end

  class SimSubClassA
    #...
  end

  class SimSubClassB
    #...
  end
end
```

I'd like to pull the subclasses into their own files for better organization.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem this idea will improve organization. If it has too much code, try create new classes to attend your needs. But if you really need, trying looking for some gem. I can't help you with implementation.